# How to add a prefix icon to TextFormField without shifting the label?

Tags: flutter, flutter-textformfield, inputformatter

I'm developing Flutter application and I want to add prefix icon to my `TextFormField` widget. Something like that:
[image]

And when I try to add a prefix icon, my label aligns (vertically) with the text, but I don't want to add an offset to the label. How can I avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

So, I just added offset to prefix icon:

```
Transform.translate(
 offset: Offset(-16.0, 0.0),
 child: ... // prefix icon widget
)
```